# Django rest framework, how to redirect to other viewset as post request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two viewsets: UserViewSet and GoogleViewSet.

In the GoogleViewSet I want to validate token and then redirect to UserViewSet.

```
class GoogleViewSet(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        # some logic
        password = User.objects.make_random_password()
        return redirect(reverse('v1_users:user_create'),
                        kwargs={'email': 'test@test.com', 'username': 'test', 'password': password})
```

But on redirect I got 405 Error

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

How can I redirect as post request?

Have tried this, but got empty request.data

```
class UserViewSet(ViewSet):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        return Response()


class GoogleViewSet(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request):
        password = User.objects.make_random_password()
        return HttpResponseTemporaryRedirect(
            '/v1/users/',
            content=json.dumps({'email': 'test@test.com', 'username': 'test', 'password': password})
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need status code 307 for that. Normally redirect will give you 302, unless it's a permanent redirect, in which case it's 301. Both transform the request into GET.

307 is like 302, but maintains the request method and body.

You can subclass `HttpResponseRedirectBase` like so:

```
class HttpResponseTemporaryRedirect(HttpResponseRedirectBase):
    status_code = 307
```

and use this response class in the view

Comment: Nice, thanks. And how can I pass request body in that way?

Comment: You don't. It happens automatically.

Comment: strange, I get empty request.body after the redirect

Comment: in DRF it's `request.data`

Comment: I know. It's empty

Comment: Could you share your views? I tested it before posting and it works as expected.

Comment: Why are you passing `content` to the response? It needs only the destination url. Also `return Response()` should be `return Response(data)` if you want to see the data in the response.

Comment: Still empty body with only destination url. Can your provide the code you have tested?

Comment: Made mistake in previous comment (which is deleted). Updating request.data does not help. So, the question is still open: how the UserViewSet can get the request.data ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237168/discussion-between-4140tm-and-headmaster).